# Sort on array inside mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I've a little PHP script that get results from my database. In the `mysql_fetch_array()` I count files on the server in a folder. I get the folder name of the MySQL results.

What I want is to build a list with all companynames and a total of all the files from the associated folder.

Well, so far so good. But the problem is I want to sort the list on the total of files.

My script look like this:

```
<? $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$_COOKIE['users_id']."'"; $sql = mysql_query("$query");
while ($fill = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { 
   $multi_user = $fill['multi_user'];
   $folder = $fill['folder'];
   $company_name = $fill['company_name'];

   $directory_purchase = '/var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/private/'.$folder.'/purchase/';
   $directory_sales = '/var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/private/'.$folder.'/sales/';
   $email_folder = '/var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/private/'.$folder.'/email/';
   $kas_folder = '/var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/private/'.$folder.'/bank/';
   $multi_folder = '/var/www/vhosts/domain.nl/private/'.$folder.'/multi/';

   $total_purchase = count(glob($directory_purchase."*.*"));
   $total_sales = count(glob($directory_sales."*.*"));
   $total_email = count(glob($email_folder."*.*"));
   $total_kas = count(glob($kas_folder."*.*"));
   $total_multi = count(glob($multi_folder."*.*"));

   $total = $total_purchase + $total_sales + $total_email + $total_kas + $total_multi;

   echo '<table>
     <tr>
         <td>'. $company_name. '</td>
         <td>'. $total .'</td>
     </tr>
   </table>';
}?>
```

Somebody know how to do this?

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...just create an array and fill it during the loop. Then sort the array and loop again. Additionally you need to cache the company names:

```
<?
$totals = array();
$companies = array();
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$_COOKIE['users_id']."'";
$sql = mysql_query("$query");
while ($fill = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { 
   // all the other stuff

   $total = $total_purchase + $total_sales + $total_email + $total_kas + $total_multi;
   $totals[$fill['id']] = $total;
   $companies[$fill['id']] = $fill['company_name']; 
}
asort($totals);
foreach ($totals as $company => $total) {
    echo $companies[$company] . ': ' . $total . '<br />';
}
?>
```

Obviously you also could put all information into one single array and use `usort()`, but in my opionion that's a little overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider sorting data within `MySql`. If you really need to do it in PHP use `usort` function (user-sort):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

`usort` functon must take two parameters (compared items) and returns `-1`, `0` or `1` if `item1` is "less", "equal" or "greater" than `item2` respectively.

Example:

```
$mydata = ... // some data

usort( $mydata, function($item1,$item2){
    // your sort logic
    return $item1['column1'] > $item2['columns1']; //simple numeric sort
});
```

Taking into account your example, you probably want to sort item by string values. It that case for sort logic use `str_cmp` to see which item is greater from another withing data array:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php

Example:

```
usort( $mydata, function($item1,$item2){
    // your sort logic
    return str_cmp($item1['folder'], $item2['folder']); //string sort
});
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: The totals wich I want to sort on are results that don't get from the database...

Comment: Well in that case this should do it :) I have edited my answer to include another example...

Comment: I can't see how this answer solves the problem? The value to sort by is the number of files on the system, that belong to a certain company. Only the company information is retrieved from the database. The file count is retrieved afterwards. I can't see any strings being relevant for sorting here.

Comment: @TillHelgeHelwig My assumption was wrong, but I didn't want to edit answer as it might be useful anyways...

The point is explanation of `usort` functioning...

Comment: I can see how in general this might be helpful, but in this case the obvious problem is that the OP did not yet come to the conclusion that using an array to cache all values migth be the solution. So while in general helpful, he basically could have got the same answer by reading the PHP documentation.